# Detect Input Value Change Inside PHP foreach from jQuery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, foreach

I have a PHP foreach loop inside a form where the value comes from database. Here, the input ID increases with the element of the loop.

```
<form class="form-horizontal">
    <?php
        $count = 0;
        foreach ($value as $row) {
            $count += 1;
            echo 
            '<div class="row">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label id="durationLabel' . $count . '">Duration (days)</label>
                    <input type="number" name="duration_days" value="' . $row['duration_days'] . ' day" class="form-control input-sm" id="durationInput' . $count . '" placeholder="Days" onchange="durationInputChange(this.value,'.$count.')">
                 </div>             
             </div>';
         }
     ?>
</form>
```

Now, my question is, how can I detect if any input value is changed (based on ID) and also get that value and show that in that corresponding Label using jQuery. The current JavaScript code I have doesn't do anything on value change:

```
function durationInputChange(a,i) { 
    var d = document.getElementById("durationInput"+i).value; 
    alert(d);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot  use `change` merely if you want more and faster feedback. The `change` is event is executed after blurring the input element. You can add `keyup`, `keydown`, and more like `paste`. Furthermore, you don't need the `onchange` attribute--no for inline binding and event listeners.

```js
$(function(){
  
  $('input[name="input-1"]').on('keyup change paste keydown', function(){
    
    var $this = $(this); 
    
    console.log($this.attr('id')); // ID; for referencing 
    console.log($this.val()); // value of this input

  });

})
```

```css
input {
  display:block;
  margin-bottom:10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input name="input-1" value="" id="input-1">
<input name="input-1" value="" id="input-2">
<input name="input-1" value="" id="input-3">
<input name="input-1" value="" id="input-4">
<input name="input-1" value="" id="input-5">
<input name="input-1" value="" id="input-6">
<input name="input-1" value="" id="input-7">
<input name="input-1" value="" id="input-8">
<input name="input-1" value="" id="input-9">
<input name="input-1" value="" id="input-10">
<input name="input-1" value="" id="input-11">
<input name="input-1" value="" id="input-12">
<input name="input-1" value="" id="input-13">
```

Answer (score 1):

Remove `onchange` action you had in your form and add `input-duration` to class:

```
<form class="form-horizontal">
    <?php
        $count = 0;
        foreach ($value as $row) {
            $count += 1;
            echo 
            '<div class="row">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label id="durationLabel' . $count . '">Duration (days)</label>
                    <input type="number" name="duration_days" value="' . $row['duration_days'] . ' day" class="form-control input-sm input-duration" id="durationInput' . $count . '" placeholder="Days">
                 </div>             
             </div>';
         }
     ?>
</form>
```

Put this code on top of your file (or below), inside `script` tag:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.input-duration').change(function() {
        // Access changed input element using $(this)

        // Get value
        alert($(this).val());

        // Get ID
        alert($(this).attr('id'));
    });
});
```

More information about jQuery attributes can be found here: https://api.jquery.com/category/attributes/

Answer (score 1):

There is no need to pass `$count` in the function, simply use `this.value` and it will pass the value of clicked input and and you can alert the value directly like this :

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.form-control').change(function(){
    alert($(this).val());
  })
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label id="durationLabel">Duration (days)</label>
    <input type="number" name="duration_days" value="' . $row['duration_days'] . ' day" class="form-control input-sm" id="durationInput1" placeholder="Days">
  </div>             
</div>

<div class="row">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label id="durationLabel2">Duration (days)</label>
    <input type="number" name="duration_days" value="' . $row['duration_days'] . ' day" class="form-control input-sm" id="durationInput2" placeholder="Days">
  </div>             
</div>
```

Comment: Hey, thanks. Your solution also works. But as I wanted the solution with jQuery, had to select the other solution as answer. :)

Comment: Welcome dear @TanvirSourov, I've changed from JS to jQuery you can also try this method ;) :)